# hover menu border bottom disappears

Tags: html, css, wordpress

as long as i login to wordpress hover menu border bottom appears but the moment i logged out and check  menu hover border bottom disappears. below is my css code any solution for it now

```
.customize-support .navbar-v1 .navbar-nav > li > a:hover {
     opacity: 1;
}
.customize-support .navbar-v1 .navbar-nav > li > a::after{
    transition: 300ms;
    height: 3px;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
   background-color: #0099cc;
    width: 0%;
    bottom: 10px;
    display:flex;   
}
.customize-support .navbar-v1 .navbar-nav > li > a:hover::after{
width:65%;
display:block;
}
```

you can also see attached image below

[image]

Comment: are you using some kind of caching plugin like wprocket or hummingbird ? if so try deleting the cache as both of them will load a uncashed version if logged into the website

Comment: i am using LiteSpeed Cache plugin, is it affecting using this???

Comment: It may be yes, personally I have only used  wprocket or hummingbird and not LiteSpeed so I can't tell 100% for sure but as both those behave in the same way (load uncashed pages while logged in) LithSpeed may do the same. If you made changes to the css or theme settings etc. it may require deleting the cach. I found this page with [documentation](https://docs.litespeedtech.com/lscache/manualpurge/) of LiteSpeed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect its cause the classname `.customize-support` is only applied if you are logged in... a possible fix would be to remove it in your css like below making the css work in both cases (logged-in and logged-out):

```
.navbar-v1 .navbar-nav > li > a:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
.navbar-v1 .navbar-nav > li > a::after{
    transition: 300ms;
    height: 3px;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #0099cc;
    width: 0%;
    bottom: 10px;
    display:flex;   
}
.navbar-v1 .navbar-nav > li > a:hover::after{
    width:65%;
    display:block;
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

To keep the underline on the parent menu item when active:

Update this:

```
.navbar-v1 .navbar-nav > li > a:hover::after, {
    width: 65%;
    display: block;
}
```

To this:

```
.navbar-v1 .navbar-nav > li > a:hover::after,
.navbar-v1 .navbar-nav > li.current-menu-parent > a::after {
    width: 65%;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @mikerojas that helped removing .customize-support classname

Comment: is there any problem while using LiteSpeed plugin ?? @mikerojas

Comment: one more question 4 you, after clicking on particular menu link,  that should remain active (focus) with bottom border but now bottom border does not show what to do ??

Comment: Updated my answer to include a fix for the underline when active... I have not used LiteSpeed so cant say good or bad.

Comment: could you please see this question by following below link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66458654/showing-theme-name-in-every-link-everywhere

Comment: as you said to include css code that works,  but only with parent menu but not in every menu items

Comment: Change `.current-menu-parent` to `.current-menu-item` for all menu items.

Comment: see this question please :                     
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66505095/logo-and-text-next-to-it-at-the-bottom-in-wordpress