# Logo and text next to it at the bottom in wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I want to make a header where i have a logo  and text next to it at the bottom but i want the text to appear at the bottom of the image . How would i achieve that?

here is my image:
[image]

her is my web url:

```
https://cloudnextservices.com
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="display:flex; flex-direction:column; align-items:center;">

<?php if (function_exists('the_custom_logo')) {the_custom_logo(); }?>

<title><?php wp_title(''); ?></title>

</div>
```

Comment: i want to write text CloudNext Services at the bottom of logo, and where i need to write ???

Comment: as I can see "CloudNext Services" is the title of the Website. If you put the php tag in the header.php as i mentioned the title will automatically appear. You can than give an id to the <title id="websiteHeaderTitle"> .. to give via css your specific look

Comment: please help me out in this question   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66505553/styling-sub-menu-header-in-wordpress

Comment: does my solution helps? > Please mark as answered

Comment: the code which you gave me as it is pasted but did not help

Comment: How does your Head-Section actually looks like? Can you please paste in (exclude all important things)

Comment: go through this link:  https://cloudnextservices.com

Comment: when I select it correct you had a class="site-logo" > this div you have to edit with flags i provided to you

Comment: title tag should not be used outside head. You can use [figure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figure) if you wish.

Comment: but that code is not reflecting in my web, what to do next, that reflects elsewhere???