# styling sub-menu header in wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, menu

i wanna make sub-menu style please help me out, you can see attached image as below :

[image]

my web link:

https://cloudnextservices.com

Answer (score 0):

This is a Css tag like:

```
li:before {
  content: '§';
}
```

If this helps > mark as answered

Comment: Please do not only use copy&paste.
If your Nav has and id > call it in css with li tag like for example: #nav_container li:before{content: '§';}

If it has no id > provide your nav element an id

Comment: what symbol did you use in the content??

Comment: as you want to > the paragraph symbol: §

Comment: no, i want the sub-menu style in three column like image

Comment: https://codepen.io/potthe/pen/LYbJyZy   /   a Way you can do it. I hope you get inspired :)

Comment: yes definately correct, but how can i use html in header because header file is in .php ??

Comment: the html construct is just an example. It should work with wordpress nav (from ccs) otherwise you have to decline an id to the nav. But furthermore I need access via ftp and you have to costly hire me as a Designer ;)

Comment: your nav should like: <nav>
                <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'header_menu' ) ); ?>
            </nav> in header.php

try to add the id <nav id="topNav">.... and I will change the css in codePen edit

Comment: css is changed - so you just have to change the id of your nav